# Offset Edge Loop Cut

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to get even offset loop cuts on selected edges on my mesh. I tried 2 ways, one with the Offset Edge loop cut, and the other with the bevel. The bevel option keeps the edges aligned perpendicular vertical & horizontal, but moves the rectangles on the mesh. The offset loop cut even I tried with the option even in the settings, makes the lines non perpendicular, and also creates a triangle face when offsetting. What's the correct method to achieve even off cut loops?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offset Edge Slide seems to behaves quite irregular. A created vertex in a corner that moves inward doesn't do so consistent with the distance of other vertices and edges, and the outward side doesn't create a vertex. (not sure how to easily change that)

But in this specific case a Bevel in combination with Knife Project might do the job:

1. Copy the cube object and create the edge offset by Bevel.
2. Select the edges you like, duplicate them, Press <kbd>P</kbd> and Separate by Selection to make them a separate object. Then move them over/above the original object.
3. In Object Mode select the edges object, then Shift select the original cube object, and (with both objects selected) go into Edit mode.
4. Press numpad <kbd>7</kbd> so the knife cut will be projected onto the desired surface at the right angle, in this case downward.
5. Apply Knife Project. In Edit Mode, 3D Viewport > Mesh > Knife Project.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great tip. it did the job, too bad Blender doesn't handle the offset edge loop in a more simple function. But if this is the best was for the result, then I go with the flow.

https://ibb.co/yFF0Mq2